# Parallel workers initialized with individual objects in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need a number of workers in Python that is initialized with an object. The main process will send commands+arguments to the workers that should then execute methods in their object and return the result in parallel.

I have tried with multiprocessing.pool, but when calling pool.map, it seems random which process is executing with which argument, even when the pool is initialized with N processes and chunksize is set to 1.

```
import multiprocessing


def init(a):
    global myA
    myA = a


def get_value(_):
    global myA
    return myA.value


class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 4
    a_lst = [A(i) for i in range(N)]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(N)
    pool.map(init, a_lst, chunksize=1)
    print(pool.map(get_value, range(N), chunksize=1))
```

output

```
[3, 1, 3, 1]
```

Can I do it with multiprocessing.pool or how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that does not depend on either the pool size or *chunksize* value, i.e. where you do not care which pool process is assigned to the tasks being submitted with the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` method, is to initialize each pool process with the entire `a_list` list by using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments on the pool initializer.

In the following code I have purposely made the size of `a_lst` and the pool size different and I am letting the `map` method compute a default *chunksize* value

```py
import multiprocessing

def init_pool(*args):
    global a_lst

    a_lst = args[0]

def get_value(i):
    return a_lst[i].value

class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 10 # list is length 10
    POOL_SIZE = 4 # pool size is 4

    a_lst = [A(i) for i in range(N)]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(POOL_SIZE, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(a_lst,))
    print(pool.map(get_value, range(N)))
```

Prints:

```None
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Booboo is simple and works fine for many cases. I have come up with an other solution, because in my case, the `a_lst` cannot be shared between the processes as each `A`-object will interact with a dll. Furthermore,   I need to send large amounts of data to each process so I assume it is better if I don't need to send all data (for all processes) to all processes

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue


def run(cls, inputQueue, outputQueue, cls_args, **kwargs):
    o = cls(*cls_args, **kwargs)
    while True:
        method, args, kwargs = inputQueue.get()
        outputQueue.put(getattr(o, method)(*args, **kwargs))


class ProcessClass():
    cls = None

    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
        self.inputQueue = Queue()
        self.outputQueue = Queue()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'cls': self.cls, 'inputQueue': self.inputQueue, 'outputQueue': self.outputQueue,
                       'cls_args': args})
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, kwargs=kwargs)
        process.start()
        return self

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            if hasattr(self.cls, name):
                def wrap(*args, wait_for_result=True, **kwargs):
                    self.inputQueue.put((name, args, kwargs))
                    if wait_for_result:
                        return self.outputQueue.get()
                return wrap
            else:
                raise

    def get_result(self):
        return self.outputQueue.get()


class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_slow_value(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        return self.value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 3
    a_lst = [ProcessClass(A)(i) for i in range(N)]  # A instantiated in sub processes
    for new_value, a in enumerate(a_lst, 10):
        a.set_value(new_value)  # set new value and return immediately

    for a in a_lst:
        a.get_slow_value(wait_for_result=False)  # call method but do not wait for result

    print([a.get_result() for a in a_lst])  # wait for results and print
```

**Update by Booboo**

When I run this it prints out **[10, 11, 12]** and then hangs forever. The problem is the `while True` loop in function `run`, which will hang on the call to `inputQueue.get()`. The fix for this is to make your processes *daemon* processes so that they do not prevent the main process from terminating. So in method `ProcessClass.__call__` the one-line change should be:

```py
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, kwargs=kwargs, daemon=True)
```

The code has a two limitations: First, if for example you wanted to invoke multiple methods in an `A` instance with *wait_for_result=False* and then call `ProcessClass.get_result` to get the multiple results you can't without calling this method repeatedly the exact number of times equal to the number of outstanding results you are expecting. Second, you cannot intermix method calls on an `A` instance with different values of the `wait_for_result` argument.

We can handle the first limitation: Let's modify the `while True:` loop in function `run` to handle the possibility of multiple calls being made on the remote object, which can result in multiple values being returned. As an example let's add an additional methods `square_value` and `cube_value` to class `A`. When `ProcessClass.get_result` is called a *sentinel* value is placed on the input queue. When the `while True:` loop in function `run` sees this sentinel it will just copy it to the output queue. Then, method `ProcessClass.get_result` will accumulate a result list taking results from the output queue until it sees a sentinel:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue

class Sentinel:
    pass

def run(cls, inputQueue, outputQueue, cls_args, **kwargs):
    o = cls(*cls_args, **kwargs)
    while True:
        item = inputQueue.get()
        if isinstance(item, Sentinel):
            # No more actual results. Put sentinel on output queue:
            outputQueue.put(item)
        else:
            method, args, kwargs = item # Unpack
            outputQueue.put(getattr(o, method)(*args, **kwargs))


class ProcessClass():
    cls = None

    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
        self.inputQueue = Queue()
        self.outputQueue = Queue()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'cls': self.cls, 'inputQueue': self.inputQueue, 'outputQueue': self.outputQueue,
                       'cls_args': args})
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, kwargs=kwargs, daemon=True)
        process.start()
        return self

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            if hasattr(self.cls, name):
                def wrap(*args, wait_for_result=True, **kwargs):
                    self.inputQueue.put((name, args, kwargs))
                    if wait_for_result:
                        return self.outputQueue.get()
                return wrap
            else:
                raise

    def get_result(self):
        self.inputQueue.put(Sentinel())
        results = []
        while True:
            item = self.outputQueue.get()
            if isinstance(item, Sentinel):
                # No more results to be obtained:
                return results
            results.append(item)


class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_slow_value(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        return self.value

    def square_value(self, x):
        return x * x

    def cube_value(self, x):
        return x * x * x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 3
    a_lst = [ProcessClass(A)(i) for i in range(N)]  # A instantiated in sub processes
    for new_value, a in enumerate(a_lst, 10):
        a.set_value(new_value)  # set new value and return immediately

    for x, a in enumerate(a_lst, 2):
        a.square_value(x, wait_for_result=False) # call method but do not wait for result
        a.square_value(-x, wait_for_result=False) # call method but do not wait for result
    print([a.get_result() for a in a_lst])  # wait for results and print
    
    for x, a in enumerate(a_lst, 2):
        a.cube_value(x, wait_for_result=False) # call method but do not wait for result
        a.cube_value(-x, wait_for_result=False) # call method but do not wait for result
    print([a.get_result() for a in a_lst])  # wait for results and print
```

Prints:

```None
[[4, 4], [9, 9], [16, 16]]
[[8, -8], [27, -27], [64, -64]]
```